# Splitting list using a list of indices

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm trying to split a list into groups based on index pairs from another list, given:

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> idx = [0, 5]
```

I need to break up the list resulting in:

```
>>> l[0:5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l[5:]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The list `idx` will at a minimum always be `[0]`, but may be of size `n`; values inside `idx` will always be sorted ascending.

Currently I have:

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> idx = [0, 5]
>>> idx.append(None)
>>> [l[idx[i]:idx[i + 1]] for i in range(len(idx) - 1)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without explicitly appending `Non` and iterating over a range?

**Edit:** for another example...

Given:

```
>>> l = list(range(14))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
>>> idx = [0, 5, 10]
```

Desired result:

```
[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try about `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l = list(range(14))
idx = [0, 5, 10]
print([l[pre: next] for pre, next in zip_longest(idx,idx[1:])])
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 3):

With `numpy` you can use `numpy.split()`

```
import numpy as np

res =[list(x) for x in np.split(l, idx) if x.size != 0]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Comment: Neat, but it would be the only use for `numpy` in the script and seems like a bulldozer being used to move a pebble. Definitely cataloging it though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = [l[curr_idx:curr_idx+idx[1]] for curr_idx in idx]
```

result

```py
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Comment: Works only for the special case `idx = [0, x, x*2, x*3, ...]`

Comment: check for this `idx = [0, 4, 11]` it gives this `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [11, 12, 13]]`

Comment: `curr_idx:curr_idx+idx[1]`.The logic is wrong.This would only work under some specific circumstances.